# Зачем нужен аргумент malloc в C?

Tags: c, malloc, heap

Я начал изучать си по одной книге. Там был такой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char *char_ptr;
    int *int_ptr;
    int mem_size;

    mem_size = 1;
    printf("\t[+] allocation %d bytes of memory on the heap for char_ptr\n", mem_size);
    char_ptr = (char *) malloc(mem_size);
    strcpy(char_ptr, "This is memory is located on the heap");
    printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n",char_ptr,char_ptr);
}
```

Тут я выделяю 1 байт для кучи. Потом записываю туда текст "This is memory is located on the heap". Я думал, что будет ошибка, ткк для текста нужно больше чем 1 байт. Но мне вернулся такой результат:

```
[+] allocation 1 bytes of memory on the heap for char_ptr
char_ptr (0x55e250f6c670) --> 'This is memory is located on the heap'
```

Из этого примера у меня один вывод: Куча увеличилась сама? Но если она увеличала объем, то зачем нужен аргумент malloc()?
Можете объяснить почему это работает?

Comment: Посмотрите на результат работы немного измененной программы - https://ideone.com/mTgAAR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код - неправильный. Нет, выделенный блок памяти не увеличился. Вы пишете за границы блока, так что у вас в коде - [неопределенное поведение](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Ошибка в таких случаях не гарантируется.

---

Подробнее:

> Я думал, что будет ошибка

Чтобы ошибка была, компилятор должен сгенерировать какой-то код, проверяющий выход за границы выделенного блока памяти.

В общем случае это - нетривиальная задача. К тому же, программы с такими проверками работали бы медленнее.

Поэтому компиляторы (с настройками по умолчанию) обычно не добавляют подобные проверки.

В свою очередь, стандарт не требует наличия этих проверок. Вместо этого, там написано, что выход за границы массива или выделенного блока памяти вызывает *неопределенное поведение*. Это означает, что программа может вести себя как угодно.

Обычно в таких ситуациях, как ваша, программа либо изменяет значения несвязанных, но находящихся рядом в памяти переменных; либо вылетает немедленно; либо вылетает через какое-то время в каком-то другом месте; либо вообще ничего не происходит.

У некоторых компиляторов есть настройки, включающие защиту от подобных ошибок (`-fsanitize=address` у GCC и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Это не работает. Записывая в массив больше элементов, чем его размер, вы получаете переполнение буфера. Эта ситуация приводит к Неопределенному Поведению. В С / С++ программист обязан следить, чтобы данные всегда записывались строго в ранее выделенной памяти.